# Why does this paint (or stain, or whatever) not want to stick to my fence?

Tags: painting, fence, stain

I've spent an hour or so painting this fence (more unpictured), but the paint I'm using seems to be really pathetic at actually colouring the fence. Is this even the right paint for the job?

The fence:
[image: Picture of fence]

The paint:
[image: Picture of paint]

Comment: Note that the product label says "rough sawn fences and sheds", and appears to be more of a stain than a paint. That could explain why it isn't soaking into areas where the grain is already sealed by past treatment. You could try sanding the fence to open the grain, or get a real exterior paint, or both...

Comment: Did you power wash the fence first? Exterior wood needs to be thoroughly cleaned before being stained or painted. Power washing is the best way too accomplish this especially if treated with deck wash first.

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues include, but are not limited to, the fence is not clean, the paint is not stirred well, and/or the paint has expired.

If you are having trouble getting the paint to stick to the fence, the problem is likely due to a dirty/moldy fence. If the paint seems thin, keep stirring the paint (most of the pigment has probably settled to the bottom).

Comment: The paint is new and it was well mixed beforehand. The actual mixture looked like it had a consistent colour. I've got the feeling this isn't actually paint, but some sort of stain. It dries very quickly and appears to wash off of skin with just water.

Comment: @JamEngulfer Oh, you got me! It wasn't paint! That _was_ tricky.

Comment: Are you just being sarcastic?

Comment: @JamEngulfer Not sarcastic at all, it certainly is funny though. I/we just took _paint_ for granted. I looked online and [Ronseal doesn't say what it is](http://www.ronseal.co.uk/garden/sheds-and-fences/one-coat-fence-life/)... they call it a "product"... and "opaque"... so I guess you have something else. The SDS is not informative, but the [product reviews on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ronseal-Coat-Fencelife-Cedar-Litre/product-reviews/B004ISTAVU) seem to indicate that it's watery and washes away in rain. I think you should write a review on Amazon. Pathetic at coloring...

Comment: Well, those reviews don't look promising. I guess I'll have to wait until it rains to see if it all washes out

Comment: @Ben Welborn: In light of your last comment you should probably edit your answer to include (just): this paint probably sucks.